# How to modify column names when combining rows of multiple columns into single rows in a dataframe based on a categorical value. + selective sum/mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm using the pandas `.groupby` function to combine multiple rows into a single row.

Currently I have a dataframe `df_clean` which has **405 rows, and 85 columns**. There are up to 3 rows that correspond to a single `Batch`.

My current code for combining the multiple rows is:

```
num_V = 84 #number of rows -1 for the row "Batch" that they are being grouped by
max_row = df_clean.groupby('Batch').Batch.count().max()
df2= (
        df_clean.groupby('Batch')
        .apply(lambda x: x.values[:,1:].reshape(1,-1)[0])
        .apply(pd.Series)
)
```

This code works creating a dataframe `df2` which groups the rows by `Batch`, however the columns in the resulting dataframe are simply numbered (0,1,2,3,...249,250,251) note that 84*3=252, ((number of columns - Batch column)*3)=252, `Batch` becomes the index.

I'm cleaning some data for analysis and I want to combine the data of several (generally 1-3) `Sub_Batch` values on separate rows into a single row based on their `Batch`. Ideally I would like to be able to determine which columns are grouped into a row and remain separate columns in the row, as well as which columns the average, or total value is reported.

for example desired input/output:

[Original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxyjF.png)

[Output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRlgy.png)
note: naming of columns, and that all columns are copied over and that the columns are ordered according to which sub-batch they belong to. ie `Weight_2` will always correspond to the second `sub_batch` that is a part of that `Batch`, `Weight_3` will correspond to the third `Sub_batch` that is part of the `Batch`.

[Ideal output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C69Y.png)
note: naming of columns, and that in this dataframe there is only a single column that records the `Color` as they are identical for all `Sub-Batch` values within a `Batch`. The individual `Temperature` values are recorded, as well as the average of the `Temperature` values for a `Batch`. The individual `Weight` values are recorded as well as the sum of the weight values in the column 'Total_weight`

I am 100% okay with the **Output Dataframe** scenario as I will simply add the values that I want afterwards using `.mean` and `.sum` for the values that I desire, I am simply asking if it can be done using `.groupby' as it is not something that I have worked with before, and I know that it does have some ability to sum or average results.

Comment: You want a pivot using a helper column

Comment: Ping me to tomorrow if you don't manage and no one answered in the meantime ;)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.